# Google website optimizer and sub-domain tracking

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, google-website-optimizer

I am setting up an A/B test with Google's website optimizer.

I have a page:

```
wwww.example.com/landingpage
```

and some variations:

```
www.example.com/landingpage0
www.example.com/landingpage1
www.example.com/landingpage2
```

the conversion page is on:

```
www.subdomain.example.com/goal
```

Website Optimizer's wizard interface, is not accepting the goal page because it's on "a different domain" and apparently there's no way to proceed with the next step.
However, if I "fake" the procedure, and specify

```
wwww.example.com/fakeGoalPage
```

the wizard will allow me to continue the set-up.

What I do next is to put the goal-page code in my real goal page, and hope that the test will work.
My question is if this practice is correct or if you can suggest me a better way to solve this problem..

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Google Website Optimizer sets its cookies on the current domain (`document.domain`). So, the cookies from `www.example.com` won't be available when they convert on `subdomain.example.com`. The solution to that is to follow the instructions from this help center: [Customizing Google Website Optimizer code for multiple subdomains?](http://www.google.com/support/websiteoptimizer/bin/answer.py?answer=117912)

Basically:

First, you add the following line just before your control script:

```
 _udn = ".example.com";
```

Then you change your tracking and conversion scripts to allow for cross domain cookies.

Assuming you're using the async syntax, that means this goes before the `gwo._trackPageview`.

```
_gaq.push(['gwo._setDomainName', '.example.com']);
```

(An alternative is to set your goal as a URL on `example.com`, create that page, and then place the conversion script as the only thing on that page, and include it as an iframe on the conversion page.)